# How do I add an image using pillow to my tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-unicode

I'm making a GUI using tkinter in python, where I need to add an image in my window.

```
load= Image.open("C:\Users\prerk\Python Projects\Computer Project SEM 1\quizpic.jpg")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(start, image=render)
img.place(x=290, y=70)
```

This is throwing the following error:

```
load= Image.open("C:\Users\prerk\Python Projects\Computer Project SEM 1\quizpic.jpg")

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong and how I should correct this?

Comment: write this `Image.open(r"C:\Users\prerk\Python Projects\Computer Project SEM 1\quizpic.jpg")`

Comment: Yess, it worked! Thank you so much. Could you please tell me what this does?

Comment: In a python **r** before a string mean that the string a raw string. When a **r** is present before a string, a character following a backslash included in the string without any change.

Comment: above code is working ?

Comment: I see, thank you very much. Yes, my code is running now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use raw strings

Image.open(r"C:\Users\prerk\Python Projects\Computer Project SEM 1\quizpic.jpg")